# HJCache moHandlerFailed HJMoHandler

Tags: iphone, hjcache

I've always used HJCache without problems, but with a particular imageset in a tableview i get continuous errors.

`2011-10-31 13:39:12.890 Koopeenveilinghuis[5576:607] moHandlerFailed HJMOHandler  users:1 retains:3
2011-10-31 13:39:19.809 Koopeenveilinghuis[5576:607] HJMOHandler URLConnection failed Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x4cc9020 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x4cbfed0 "unsupported URL"}
2011-10-31 13:39:19.811 Koopeenveilinghuis[5576:607] moHandlerFailed HJMOHandler  users:2 retains:4
2011-10-31 13:39:19.823 Koopeenveilinghuis[5576:607] moHandlerFailed HJMOHandler  users:2 retains:4
2011-10-31 13:39:32.106 Koopeenveilinghuis[5576:607] HJMOHandler URLConnection failed Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x4ccc0e0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x4ccc110 "unsupported URL"}
2011-10-31 13:39:32.111 Koopeenveilinghuis[5576:607] moHandlerFailed HJMOHandler  users:1 retains:3`

Images overlap every couple of cells.

Comment: somehow on topic: had "unsupported URL" Code=-1002 with a NSUrl for 'www.stuff.something'. solved with 'http: //www.stuff.something' (remove spaces)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [NSURLErrorUnsupportedURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)
>   Returned when a properly formed URL cannot be handled by the
>   framework. The most likely cause is that there is no available
>   protocol handler for the URL.

No mistery there, the URL lacks a supported protocol. This happens because the protocol is not supported, or because the URL is missing completely. Since [NSErrorFailingURLStringKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is empty, the later seems to be the case.